# Matrix: Python adjacent

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, matrix

I have been trying to solve multiple problems. Now stuck at one and can’t seem to surpass this.

Given 2D array representing the existence of a new file on each server, write an algo that will determine the minimum num of hours required to send the file to all the servers.

**Example:**

Rows: 4
Columns: 5 
Grid:

`[[0,1,1,0,1], [0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1],[0,1,0,0,0]]`

Output: 2

Because:

At the end of the first hour, the status of their servers:

`[[1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1]]`

Second hour, all server status:

`[[1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1]]`

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Looks like homework, is missing lots of informations. What does the matrix represent? How do you send the first file over to any server if it is not present on any server according to your matrix? how many files can be sent per hour? if the file is present on 2 servers and missing on 2 servers, can it be send in parallel? if it is on 1 server and missing on 3 servers, can you send it to all 3 simultaniously? etc.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with a breadth-first search, starting from the positions that have a 1:

```
def solve(mat):
    # collect positions that have a "1"
    frontier = []
    for y, row in enumerate(mat):
        for x, val in enumerate(row):
            if val:
                frontier.append((y,x))
    # Perform a BFS starting from these positions
    count = -1
    while len(frontier):
        count += 1
        newfrontier = []
        for y, x in frontier:
            # Get all neighbors of y, x:
            for y1, x1 in ((y-1, x), (y, x-1), (y+1, x), (y, x+1)):
                # If neighbor exists, and it has a zero:
                if (y1 >= 0 and y1 < len(mat) and 
                        x1 >= 0 and x1 < len(mat[0]) and mat[y1][x1] == 0):
                    # Visit this cell, and collect it for the next iteration
                    newfrontier.append((y1, x1))
                    mat[y1][x1] = 2 # mark as visited.
        frontier = newfrontier
    return count

res = solve([
    [0,1,1,0,1], 
    [0,1,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1],
    [0,1,0,0,0]
])

print(res) # 2
```